# ASP.NET MVC / C# ShoppingCart

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I followed tutorial on how to build a shopping cart in application in MVC.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZBd0MnKb7u0

Most of the cart works, but the method Delete don't work as it should. Instead of delete one item at the time, it deletes all the items from the list.

I think the list needs a loop like a for or foreach, but I don't know how to write it.

Here my code from the controller.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Outlet.Models.Database;

namespace Outlet.Controllers
{
    public class ShoppingCartController : Controller
    {
        public Connection db = new Connection();

        // GET: Cart
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        private int isExisting(int id)
        {
            List<Item> cart = (List<Item>)Session["cart"];
            for (int i = 0; i < cart.Count; i++)
                if (cart[i].Product.productId == id)
                    return i;
            return -1;
        }

        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            int index = isExisting(id);
            List<Item> cart = (List<Item>)Session["cart"];
            cart.RemoveAt(index);

            //var lstSlet = cart.Where(x => x.Product.productId == id);
            //cart.ForEach(x => cart.Remove(x));
            Session["cart"] = cart;

            return View("Cart");
        }

        public ActionResult OrderNow(int id)
        {
            if (Session["cart"] == null)
            {
                List<Item> cart = new List<Item>();
                cart.Add(new Item(db.Products.Find(id), 1));
                Session["cart"] = cart;
            }

            else
            {
                List<Item> cart = (List<Item>)Session["cart"];
                int index = isExisting(id);
                if (index == -1)
                    cart.Add(new Item(db.Products.Find(id), 1));
                else
                    cart[index].Quantity++;
                Session["cart"] = cart;

            }
            return View("Cart");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to debug and check the value of cart when assigning Session["cart"]=cart; are you getting expected items?

Comment: I followed the YouTube tutorial step-by-step and I can delete the shopping cart items one at a time. Could you please post the rest of your code and place a break point on the Delete action and step through it and post the results you get

Comment: Year, i can delete the items to, but it is the quantity i want to remove 1-1 instead of all.

I will parse the code later to day.